# Grafica basada en porcentajes, Mapeo Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Basicamente quiero lograr poner una barrita o circunferencia que dependiendo de que numero sea(una variable Float por ejemplo) este mas llena o no, siendo 100 su totalidad y el resto que varie dependiendo de el estado 0 que podria ser 0 o 1.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que la pregunta es un poco ambigua pero no se ni por donde comenzar en Android Studio, Esto era algo que lograba en Unity con c# haciendo mapeos, pero aqui con kotlin no se como hacerlo.

Comment: eso se logra con circular seekbar o progressBar

Comment: Funciona a perfeccion, deberia de borrar la pregunta o dejarla por si alguien lo piensa de la misma manera que yo y no se topa con los elementos de progressBar ?

Comment: no la borres. Mejor responde tu mismo con un ejemplo